# How dirty is sponge grip and how to clean it?

Tags: cleaning, sports

I mean the sponge grip on a sport equipment, only for my own use. Will there be a lot of bacteria in it? If so, how should I clean it?

[image]

Comment: Is it just your own bacteria that are worrying you, or is the article grubbly and in need of a wash? Squirt some anti-bacterial hand liquid into a washing bowl, run some warm water into the bowl so that it just covers the grip. Squash the item repeatedly with the palm of your hand to expel air and move the cleaning water through the sponge cavities. Rinse a few times in warm water the same way, squeeze out any liquid, and place in a well ventilated area to dry. This is not really a "hack" - just washing instructions.

Comment: Why the close votes? There are literally thousands of "cleaning" questions on this SE: https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=clean

Comment: @SurpriseDog That is true, but they are voting to close because "everyday "How to…" questions about learning a craft or new skill are outside the scope of this site"

Answer (score 1):

What is the sponge wrapped around?

If it wrapped around metal or plastic, then washing can be an easy step.

If it is wrapped around wood, then you should avoid moisture as much as possible. Eventually, if the grip is removable, you might want to wrap the wood with some plastic foil, for protection.

---

Wet disinfection:

- water and soap, rinse after;
- any liquid disinfectants; you might want to ask at a local pharmacy; some disinfectants might leave odors (e.g. alcohol based), others might damage the materials in some way (e.g. hydrogen peroxide);

Dry disinfection:

- UV-C light; you should be able to purchase, at least from the internet, a small UV-C lamp for disinfection - the kind that is used even by hospitals. Place the grip under that light for 30 - 60 min. Be sure to expose all areas to the light.

---

"Completely" avoid "contamination"

- wrap the grip with some plastic foil (e.g. kitchen wrapping foil), so your hand does not get in contact with the grip; replace the plastic wrap occasionally.

---

Lower the rate at which the grip gets contaminated

- you probably already do it, but just in case: wash your hands immediately before touching the grip. In that way, there is less bacteria to be transferred to the sponge.

Answer (score 0):

You can make water base solution using tea tree oil. Great for disinfection! spray on it leave it on and then wipe it off. I believe for home use equipment that's enough.